# strange printer problem

Tags: networking, printing, hp

I have a System76 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and an HP OfficeJet Pro 6978. For some reason, the printer stopped accepting any print jobs a few weeks ago, although it worked fine before. If I open the printer's IP address in a browser, it will print it's status report showing it's connected to my network router. Similarly, the HP Network Configuration page from HP Device Manager prints out and says it's connected. But it I try to print any document from the laptop, it won't print and it give this error: "Stopped - Backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/implicitclass does not exist! How can I fix this? Should I re-install the Ubuntu system or is there some easier way?

Comment: Try running `hp-setup` from the terminal. If the printer is not discovered, manually enter the IP address of the printer. If `hp-setup` is not there install using the following command: `udo apt install hplip hplip-gui`

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/lib/cups/backend/implicitclass` give?

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1905841 It could be that reinstalling hplip might solve it

Comment: brian_p: that command gives ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/cups/backend/implicitclass': No such file or directory

Comment: @user68186 and Ohiovr: reinstalling hplip and trying to connect with the IP address the printer reports, or using the network printer search in the gui  says "can't find any printer" and a bunch of errors including it might not connect due to firewall settings. But I get the same result if I turn the firewall (Gufw.py) off. Oddly, another laptop that I have which as an older version of Ubuntu prints just fine, so I think when I have to print something I'll transfer the file to that laptop. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: @user663877 The implicitclass filter is provided by cups-filters. Do `apt --reinstall install cups-filters`.

Comment: None of the suggestions I've found here or elsewhere on the web have worked. I just went through reinstalling cups and hplip and when I start hplip-setup it can't find the printer! I can print documents from an older laptop that still has Ubuntu 18.04 on it so if I need to print, I can transfer files to that one. I do wish Ubuntu would get it's act together on this. I really don't want to overwrite it with a Windows system!